# Why new URL() method removes one part of my url passed as a base url

Tags: javascript

I created a snippet to show the issue below

I have the following values to create my URL

```
const baseUrl = 'https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio';
const accessCode = 'accesscode_he-ar_IL.mp3';
```

When I run `new URL()` the result is `https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/accesscode_he-ar_IL.mp3`

Why the middle part is removed as `xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio`

I have no clue why the method removes part of my URL and this results in a fail for me as I need to get data from that path.

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio';
const accessCode = 'accesscode_he-ar_IL.mp3';

const res = new URL(accessCode, baseUrl);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: `'https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio/'` should be used as the base URL. It’s basically the same behavior with hyperlinks. If you’re on `https://example.com/index.html`, then `<a href="page2.html">` links to `https://example.com/page2.html`, not to `https://example.com/index.html/page2.html`.

Comment: You forgot to add an extra `/` at the end of your baseUrl : `const baseUrl = 'https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio/';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add an extra `/` at the end of your baseUrl : `const baseUrl = 'https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio/'`

```js
const baseUrl = 'https://s3.xxx.xxx.com/xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio/';
const accessCode = 'accesscode_he-ar_IL.mp3';

const res = new URL(accessCode, baseUrl);

console.log(res);
```

The `URL()` method replace the current page (which in your case was `xyz.xxx.xxx.twilio`) by the new page passed through the access code.

Comment: Why does `const accessCode = '/accesscode_he-ar_IL.mp3';` with a `/` prefix remove the twilio path as well even when the `baseUrl` ends with a `/`

Comment: @adiga Because `/something` indicates an origin-relative URL. See [Absolute URLs vs relative URLs](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls).